# How many Applications do Ubuntu have?

Tags: application-development

I am wondering how many applications Ubuntu have in total.

Answer (score 2):

It will be a bit a manual work but the [Ubuntu app directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/) shows the application per category with a number. So all the non-applications will be filtered from the results.

- [accesories](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/accessories/): 822
- [developer tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/developer-tools/): 245
- [education](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/education/): 396
- [games](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/): 918
- [internet](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/internet/): 406
- [office](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/office/): 242
- [science](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/science-engineering/): 226
- [sound and vision](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/sound-video/): 446
- [themes and tweaks](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/themes-tweaks/): 190
- [Universal access](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/universal-access/): 26

There are some more categories but these are the main ones in the official repositories.

Comment: Noteworthy; these are the prepackaged apps. With just slightly more knowledge you may take something outside of this bunch, and do `./configure && make all && sudo make install` to get it running.

Comment: @Hannu yep I agree and this also excludes tons of PPAs (like getdeb.net as Xen2050 said though those will hold duplicates but more updated versions too) but I decided to stick to the question  and go for the cold hard facts ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you've added the universe & multiverse and added archive.getdeb.net, then Synaptic might tell you there's about 45,000 packages listed. That includes tons of non-application packages, libraries and things. And there are lots and lots of programs written for Ubuntu or any linux that are not in the repo's, it's kind of an uncountable number.

Comment: USC shows "76264 items" at the bottom ;)